# same page, different load time on different server

Tags: mysql, vps, load-testing

I am completely new to server admin. I have built a large site (for one person to code) and have to do things myself.

I have a site on a shared server and another on a managed VPS. The VPS server holds databases with a couple of tables exceeding 650k rows.

My question is about page load times on pages not accessing any tables. For example the home pages of both domains now use the same code however their load times are dramatically different. The VPS has an SSL but I don't think that accounts for the massive difference.

Load testing gives a size of 2MB and a load time of over 9 seconds for https://openaus.net.au (VPS) and a load time of 1.83 seconds for http://infoaus.net (shared server).

The VPS is not showing any load. The only other difference I can think of is the number and size of the tables in the VPS. Can that affect page load times on pages that do not access large tables? There are nearly 60 tables in one database on the VPS.

What can be making the VPS load time so much longer than the shared server? The main VPS database size is just over 600MB and the RAM on the MySql server is just over 1000MB. I have no idea if this is a reasonable set up or whether it can affect pages not accessing any of the tables.

thanks in advance for feedback,

Comment: Tell us about the VPS. What is your CPU/RAM/Disk resource utilization? How much `iowait` are you seeing?

Comment: Tracking this down may be difficult if you're new to server admin. You may want to consider hiring someone for an hour or two.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I'll work on finding someone to help pinpoint the cause of this issue over coming days/weeks rather than experiment with it myself.